# What's the Next Step After Finding Eigenvalues for $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I've been working on a math problem involving two geometric objects in $\mathbb R^3$. The first object, which we'll call $P$, is described by the equation $x - y + 2z = 0$, and the second object, $Q$, is described by the equation $x + y = 2$.

I've successfully found the eigenvalues for these objects, and I'm wondering what the next step should be in my analysis. Specifically, I have a few questions:

(a) Do $P$ and $Q$ represent points, lines, planes, or volumes in $\mathbb R^3$?

(b) Are $P$ and $Q$ parallel to each other?

(c) How can I find the line that passes through the point $[2, -1, -1]^T$ and is parallel to both $P$ and $Q$? Please provide the answer in vector parameter form.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to proceed with these questions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: (NB: All 3 of your questions are well-formed, but since $P$ and $Q$ represent planes, I'm not sure what you mean by having found their eigenvalues.)

Comment: Your title is misleading.

Comment: Did you mean orthogonal vectors?